# Android Studio: Parsing XML not well-formed error.

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/hint_message" 
        /> 


</LinearLayout>
```

That is my code. In Android Studio 1.2.1.1, it returns the errors:

- Error:(8) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\hayden\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am using windows 8.My Code Encoding is set for windows-1252.
Please help.

Comment: You missed `>` for `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Add a closing bracket **>** after **android:orientation="horizontal"** in your LinearLayout.

Comment: It's a waste of others' time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
android:orientation="horizontal"> <!-- Here is the error you forgot to close LinearLayout-->

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="@string/hint_message" 
    /> 


</LinearLayout>
```

you forgot to write `>` after defining the properties in LinearLayout and this error you might have caught if you properly notice the color in the IDE. or you read the Error carefully.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/hint_message" 
        /> 
</LinearLayout>
```